# GWT compile not working if using gwt-chosen-3.0.1

Tags: java, gwt, gwt2

I am using GWT sdk 2.6.1
I want to use gwt-chosen-3.0.1.jar but getting error while compiling

Inherited Chosen module in App.gwt.xml

```
<define-configuration-property name="CssResource.allowedFunctions" is-multi-valued="true" />
<inherits name="com.arcbees.chosen.Chosen" />
```

> Creating assignment for css()
>                  Replacing CSS class names
>                     The following obfuscated style classes were missing from the source CSS file:
>                        [ERROR] indent: Fix by adding .indent{}
>                     [ERROR] The following unobfuscated classes were present in a strict CssResource:
>                        [ERROR] icon_check
>                        Fix by adding String accessor method(s) to the CssResource interface for obfuscated classes, or using an @external declaration for unobfuscated classes.
>               [ERROR] Generator 'com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.InlineClientBundleGenerator' threw an exception while rebinding 'com.arcbees.chosen.client.resources.Resources'
>   com.google.gwt.resources.css.ast.CssCompilerException: Missing a CSS replacement
>
> [ERROR] Errors in 'com/arcbees/chosen/client/gwt/ChosenListBox.java'
>         [ERROR] Line 103: Failed to resolve 'com.arcbees.chosen.client.resources.Resources' via deferred binding
>   [WARN] For the following type(s), generated source was never committed
>   (did you forget to call commit()?)
>         [WARN] com.arcbees.chosen.client.resources.Resources_default_InlineClientBundleGenerator
>   Computing all possible rebind results for
>   'com.arcbees.chosen.client.resources.Resources'
>         Rebinding com.arcbees.chosen.client.resources.Resources
>            Invoking generator com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.InlineClientBundleGenerator

Comment: Hi! Did you add the GQuery jar file in your classpath?

Comment: @Imaguest Yes I have added GQuery jar in my classpath

Comment: And if you remove the Chosen module import, does your application run?

Comment: yes after removing Chosen module import my Application is running fine

Comment: Try to upgrade to GWT 2.7. It seems that gwt-chosen provides some GWT dependencies (gwt-user / dev) with 2.7 version

Comment: For now it is not possible for me to upgrade to 2.7 as in my project some of the other necessary modules are supported in 2.6.1 only

Comment: For now it is not possible for me to upgrade to 2.7 as in my project some of the other necessary modules are supported in 2.6.1 only

Comment: It seems that all versions of gwt-chosen work with GWT 2.7. Maybe you should consider to search another library or find a way to upgrade your project.